# Выделение обращения

Tags: пунктуация

В обращении "эй(,) вы" или даже "эй(,) вы(,) оба..." — как ставятся запятые? "Вы оба" - это цельная конструкция или все-таки "вы" отдельно, а "оба" отдельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, что здесь возможны варианты, зависящие от интонации и смысла. "Эй, вы, оба, подойдите ко мне!" - "оба" имеет уточняющее значение. "Эй, вы оба, подойдите ко мне!" - "вы оба" имеет собирательное значение